# Extending class with hidden constructors

Tags: java, android

I have a base class `FiniteStateMachine` which has a list of `State`. The states can only be instantiated through the FSM, so I can make sure the list is updated.

```
public class FiniteStateMachine {
    private List<State> states = new ArrayList<State>();

    public State addState(String name) {
        State s = new State(name);
        states.add(s);
        return s;
    }

    protected void addState(State s) {
        states.add(State s);
    }

    public static class State {
        private String name;
        protected State(String name) { this.name = name; }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to extend both the `FiniteStateMachine` and `State` classes into `MyFSM` and `MyState` classes. I still want to make sure the new `MyState` states can only be created through the FSM, to ensure they are part of the list.
This is what I have done so far:

```
public MyState extends FinitStateMachine.State {
    private int n;

    protected MyState(int n, String name) {
        super(name);
        this.n = n;
    }
}

public MyFSM extends FiniteStateMachine {
    @Override
    public State addState(String name) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public MyState addState(int n, String name) {
        MyState s = new MyState(n, name);
        super.addState(s);
        return s;
    }

}
```

I am not sure I am doing it right.
First, the original `State` class is an inner class of `FiniteStateMachine`, and here I am extending it outside my new class `MyFSM`.
Second, I had to add a new method to the original `FiniteStatMachine`

```
    protected void addState(State s) {
        states.add(State s);
    }
```

otherwise I don't know how could I have attached a state of my new `MyState` class to the `FiniteStateMachine` list.
Third, instead of overriding the `addState(name)` method I kind of crippled it and throw an exception and instead put a whole new method to return the new class.

If there is a coding pattern for these situations I am not aware of it. But I'd like to know, so I don't go reinventing the wheel.

Comment: For me it sounds like State should be an enum.

Comment: If you need Finite State Machines, then you might want to check out [Automa](https://github.com/gscacco/automa) With it you can easily create FSM by defining states and events as plain enum and program the FSM with something like `automa.from(State_0).goTo(State_1).when(Event_X).andDon(myRunnableAction)` Then you can simply send events to the FSM by calling `automa.signalEvent(EVENT_X)` There is also an `AsynchAutoma` which dispatches the vents in its own thread.

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi Thanks, my FiniteStateMachine library is already written long time ago, and works fine, I am dealing now, for the first time, with how to extend it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make the list variable protected, you may access it from child classes too, without the add method. It depends on what you want to do later, and how visible you want the list to be. If you want to be able to add states from outside of the inheritance hierarchy, or if you don't want the list to be visible within the whole package,you may need the addState method though.

Comment: That's a good point. Thoug I think there is no avoid of a new `addState` method, even if just for the new `int` field I have to initialize.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I've been thinking a lot about it, and even almost coded a parametric `FiniteStateMachine<S extends State>` class, but I realized it is more cumbersome than my current approach. I finally decided that there should be a serious study of parametrized classes that actually use their parameters for internal behaviour, and I found none on the web, so for now I keep my appraoch as it is.